# Introduction to various Attack types

Tags: security

I just read a paper on preventing buffer overflow attacks and in that vein, I am looking for a paper or set of papers that will explain the various types of `attacks` that programmers and sysadmins have to worry about.  Can anyone help? even a keywords to search ACM under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such definitive document, or we could all read it and follow it's guidelines and be safe forever :)

There are a few organisations trying to provide information and guides on specifi areas, one of them is OWASP: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page which has lots of good information, and a [Top Ten list](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) that contains the most common subset of attacks.

There is also [CERT](http://www.us-cert.gov/) and [OSVDB](http://osvdb.org/) and many more (if anyone wants to make a definitive list of the websites, feel free to edit this post and add some.

Common Weakness Enumeration[4](http://cwe.mitre.org/)

Comment: thanks for such a quick answer.  Though, I doubt that simply knowing about the various types of attacks would be sufficient to make all code safe. also, [this](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack) is almost exactly what I was looking for, so thanks again